# SQL Server Partition - File Placement

Tags: sql-server, configuration, installation

According to Microsoft best practices you can optimize SQL and take a lot of benefits by using this technique, my only question is how to correctly install the SQL Server to match the drives/paths according to their article:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758814(v=sql.100).aspx

I got my system partitioned matching the article above:

- C: SYSTEM
- D: TEMP DATA
- E: TEMP LOGS
- F: SERVICES DATA
- G: SERVICES LOGS
- H: CONTENT DATA
- I: CONTENT LOGS
- J: BACKUP DATA

During the setup wizard I'm prompted for the directories (see below) but I can't figure the correct matching for all my drives/paths, I'm not sure at this point if my assumptions are remotely correct, even more, where do "Services Data" and "Services Log" will go? The options below aren't enough to match all my drives, I'm pretty sure I'm missing something and I'm lost here :)

[image]

My questions are:

1. How to match the drivers/directories to meet the aligned partition structure?
2. Is it possible to configure the Config.ini to automate this scenario?

Comment: The big question is what actual OS version is this running on. If it is running on Windows 2008 or later, the Partition Alignment issue has been fixed for newly created partitions (no guarantees for partitions on a server migrated from an earlier version.) Also, according to the author who best documented this issue, you should [still check the alignment on your partitions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jimmymay/2014/03/14/disk-partition-alignment-it-still-matters-dpa-for-windows-server-2012-sql-server-2012-and-sql-server-2014/)

Comment: Hi Vergil, the system where I'm going to install is Windows Server 2012 R2. I've made a good research and although misalignment is a thing of the past,  the practice still considered a good practice according to my research. So I got my system with 8 disks and I'm a little lost right now to match drivers with the correct configuration - any thoughts on this?

Comment: @Dr.Sushi, the term disk partition alignment is not the same as file placement as in your question. Disk partition alignment refers to aligning partition offsets with physical storage: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758814%28v=sql.100%29.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for the correction Guzman, you are correct, the question is file placement, any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think I nailed this thing! Took me a lot of work but I think I could put this together and here it is what I did on my system:

- C: SYSTEM = where SQL is installed
- D: TEMP DATA = Temp DB directory
- E: TEMP LOGS = Temp DB for logs
- F: SERVICES DATA = Database Engine root INSTALLSQLDATADIR=F:\ServicesData
- G: SERVICES LOGS = MSSQLServer Service startup to -G:\ServiceLogs\Logs\ERRORLOG
- H: CONTENT DATA = User database  (*.mdf)
- I: CONTENT LOGS = User database logs (*.ldf)
- J: BACKUP DATA = The SQL backups